# how to encode url on R

Tags: r, web-services, rest

how can I encode a url as this

[http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi=InchI=1S/C21H30O9/c1-11(5-6-21(28)12(2)8-13(23)9-20(21,3)4)7-15(24)30-19-18(27)17(26)16(25)14(10-22)29-19/h5-8,14,16-19,22,25-28H,9-10H2,1-4H3/b6-5+,11-7-/t14-,16-,17+,18-,19+,21-/m1/s1&token=e4a6d6fb-ae07-4cf6-bae8-c0e6115bc681](http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi=InchI=1S/C21H30O9/c1-11%285-6-21%2828%2912%282%298-13%2823%299-20%2821,3%294%297-15%2824%2930-19-18%2827%2917%2826%2916%2825%2914%2810-22%2929-19/h5-8,14,16-19,22,25-28H,9-10H2,1-4H3/b6-5+,11-7-/t14-,16-,17+,18-,19+,21-/m1/s1&token=e4a6d6fb-ae07-4cf6-bae8-c0e6115bc681)

to make this

[http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi=InChI%3D1S%2FC21H30O9%2Fc1-11(5-6-21(28)12(2)8-13(23)9-20(21%2C3)4)7-15(24)30-19-18(27)17(26)16(25)14(10-22)29-19%2Fh5-8%2C14%2C16-19%2C22%2C25-28H%2C9-10H2%2C1-4H3%2Fb6-5%2B%2C11-7-%2Ft14-%2C16-%2C17%2B%2C18-%2C19%2B%2C21-%2Fm1%2Fs1](http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi=InChI%3D1S%2FC21H30O9%2Fc1-11%285-6-21%2828%2912%282%298-13%2823%299-20%2821%2C3%294%297-15%2824%2930-19-18%2827%2917%2826%2916%2825%2914%2810-22%2929-19%2Fh5-8%2C14%2C16-19%2C22%2C25-28H%2C9-10H2%2C1-4H3%2Fb6-5%2B%2C11-7-%2Ft14-%2C16-%2C17%2B%2C18-%2C19%2B%2C21-%2Fm1%2Fs1)

on R?

I tried

URLencode

but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you piecing two variables together? How do you want to programmatically decide where the encoding should begin (because it seems you want to leave some untouched)? Did you read the `?URLencode` help page? Did you see the `reserved` parameter?

Comment: Hi MrFick, yes, I tried use reserved in just a piece of the url an then paste the two, but it seems the URLencode is not encoding everything it should.

Comment: Well, post what you tried. If you set `URLencode(...,reserved=T)` for that GET parameter, it should make your input look like your output. What is it not encoding that you think it should?

Comment: So it looks like you want to encode commas but URLEncode isn't doing that, is that correct? Is that the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to get rid of all but first URL GET data specifier and then to encode the associated data.

```
url <- "..."
library(stringi)
(addr <- stri_replace_all_regex(url, "\\?.*", ""))
## [1] "http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES"
args <- stri_match_first_regex(url, "[?&](.*?)=([^&]+)")
(data <- stri_replace_all_regex(
     stri_trans_general(args[,3], "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-()]Any-Hex/XML"),
        "&#x([0-9a-fA-F]{2});", "%$1"))
## [1] "InchI%3D1S%2FC21H30O9%2Fc1-11(5-6-21(28)12(2)8-13(23)9-20(21%2C3)4)7-15(24)30-19-18(27)17(26)16(25)14(10-22)29-19%2Fh5-8%2C14%2C16-19%2C22%2C25-28H%2C9-10H2%2C1-4H3%2Fb6-5%2B%2C11-7-%2Ft14-%2C16-%2C17%2B%2C18-%2C19%2B%2C21-%2Fm1%2Fs1"
(addr <- stri_c(addr, "?", args[,2], "=", data))
## [1] "http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi=InchI%3D1S%2FC21H30O9%2Fc1-11(5-6-21(28)12(2)8-13(23)9-20(21%2C3)4)7-15(24)30-19-18(27)17(26)16(25)14(10-22)29-19%2Fh5-8%2C14%2C16-19%2C22%2C25-28H%2C9-10H2%2C1-4H3%2Fb6-5%2B%2C11-7-%2Ft14-%2C16-%2C17%2B%2C18-%2C19%2B%2C21-%2Fm1%2Fs1"
```

Here I made use of the ICU's transliterator (via `stri_trans_general`). All characters but `A..Z`, `a..z`, `0..9`, `(`, `)`, and `-` have been converted to hexadecimal representation
(it seems that  `URLencode` does not handle `,` even with `reserved=TRUE`) of the form `&#xNN;`. Then, each `&#xNN;` was converted to `%NN` with `stri_replace_all_regex`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches:

**1) gsubfn/URLencode** If `u` is an R character string containing the URL then try this.  This inputs everything after `?` to `URLencode` replacing the input with the output of that function.  Note that `"\\K"` kills everything in the buffer up to that point so that the `?` itself does not get encoded:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\?\\K(.*)", ~ URLencode(x, TRUE), u, perl = TRUE)
```

It gives the following (which is not identical to the output in the question but may be sufficient):

[http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi%3dInchI%3d1S%2fC21H30O9%2fc1-11(5-6-21(28)12(2)8-13(23)9-20(21,3)4)7-15(24)30-19-18(27)17(26)16(25)14(10-22)29-19%2fh5-8,14,16-19,22,25-28H,9-10H2,1-4H3%2fb6-5+,11-7-%2ft14-,16-,17+,18-,19+,21-%2fm1%2fs1%26token%3de4a6d6fb-ae07-4cf6-bae8-c0e6115bc681](http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi%3dInchI%3d1S%2fC21H30O9%2fc1-11%285-6-21%2828%2912%282%298-13%2823%299-20%2821,3%294%297-15%2824%2930-19-18%2827%2917%2826%2916%2825%2914%2810-22%2929-19%2fh5-8,14,16-19,22,25-28H,9-10H2,1-4H3%2fb6-5+,11-7-%2ft14-,16-,17+,18-,19+,21-%2fm1%2fs1%26token%3de4a6d6fb-ae07-4cf6-bae8-c0e6115bc681)

**2) gsubfn/curlEscape** For a somewhat different output continuing to use gsubfn try:

```
library(RCurl)
gsubfn("\\?\\K(.*)", curlEscape, u, perl = TRUE)
```

giving:

http://www.chemspider.com/inchi.asmx/InChIToSMILES?inchi%3DInchI%3D1S%2FC21H30O9%2Fc1%2D11%285%2D6%2D21%2828%2912%282%298%2D13%2823%299%2D20%2821%2C3%294%297%2D15%2824%2930%2D19%2D18%2827%2917%2826%2916%2825%2914%2810%2D22%2929%2D19%2Fh5%2D8%2C14%2C16%2D19%2C22%2C25%2D28H%2C9%2D10H2%2C1%2D4H3%2Fb6%2D5%2B%2C11%2D7%2D%2Ft14%2D%2C16%2D%2C17%2B%2C18%2D%2C19%2B%2C21%2D%2Fm1%2Fs1%26token%3De4a6d6fb%2Dae07%2D4cf6%2Dbae8%2Dc0e6115bc681

**ADDED** `curlEscape` approach